# Xamarin debugger won't attach due dll

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a xamarin-forms pcl/android/ios) solution referencing a dll compiled from [M2Mqtt](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt) (mono).

The app worked fine and still does. I'm still able to compile an run the app on my device, except I can't debug anymore. As soon as the app starts, the breakpoints change from red dots to red circles.

It all started a while ago after I installed some updates (beginning of May). At first I thought this was due to a problem with the latest Xamarin.Forms update, but even reverting to an older one didn't help. I've installed VS2017 community for mac, but no luck. Yesterday I tried to run the debugger on VS2017 on PC, also no luck. I then started to remove references, deleting packets and now I know it's this dll I compiled which is the cause of the debugger not attaching anymore.

How ever, since the app is still working fine and since I can't do without this dll ... does anybody have an idea how I could get the debugger working again?

Best Gerrit

Comment: Is it only iOS where breakpoints aren't working? Or Android too?

Comment: All involved projects won't hit any breakpoints. Even the pcl, even though it has no reference to the dll.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got kind of a workaround. I need to unload either ios or android. Then I need to delete the reference to the dll. Then I need to comment the usings of the dll and everybit of code working with that dll. After that, I can compile and debug. I then load the unloaded project uncomment everything earlier commented and hit the debugger ... it works until the ide is restarted. WOW, very productive ;-)

Comment: Well, it's not as "good" as described. Sometimes the Breakpoints are still not being hit. I don't know ... is it the IDE or is it something I did. Tried the solution on different machines. Sometimes it's working, sometimes not.